# Using Embedly to loop Vimeo video

Tags: vimeo, embedly

I am using Embedly to show and control videos on my site. However, I would like the videos to loop. I can't find any documentation on that setting. Anyone have any ideas?

```
  <iframe id="xxx-999" class="embedly-embed" src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.vimeo.com%2Fvideo%2Fxxxx&background=1&key=internal&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=vimeo&loop=1" width="500" height="281" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/b3tnwh7q/

```
// on ended, restart the video.
player.on('ended', function(){
  player.setCurrentTime(0);
  player.play();
});
```

There looks like there is a bug in the Vimeo player that keeps the video recommendations overlaid. I'll let them know.